# Efficient way to check if an input string contains any punctuation from a string of punctuations

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, punctuation

I am working on a logic to detect if an input string contains any punctuation from a string of punctuations.

```
public boolean detectAnyPunctuation(String input, String punctuationArray){}
```

The function should return true of any of the punctuation from punctuation array is found in input string. Punctuation Array is not fixed. It could be changed with each function call. Input string cannot exceed 1000 chars.

I am thinking of converting a punctuation array to a char array and then running a loop over the char array to check for character in input string. 
Time complexity for this would be O(MN) where m are characters in punctuation array and N in input array (worst case).

Finally I implemented using regex as below,

```
public static boolean detectPunctuations(String in, String pu){ 
String puQ = “[” + pu + “]”; 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(puQ); 
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(in); 
return m.find(); 
}
```

**EDIT:**
Now I am trying to find if it contains all punctuations from punctuation string or not. It should return true only if all punctuations from punctuation string appear in the input string. Any inputs for this one please ?

Comment: If it's asymptotic complexity you're looking to minimize, a hash table would make it O(N). It's entirely possible that O(MN) is faster in practice for small M though.

Comment: What if I compile a pattern using punctuation array and then use it to match against the input string ?

Comment: `Punctuation Array is not fixed. It could be changed with each function call.` Can you elaborate on this ? Btw, isn't there any string methods like 'contains' that can do this ?

Comment: In regex, character class elements are left to right searched. So if you put the most common punctuation last in the class, it will take longer to find. Just a fyi.

Comment: If @sln is right about the JDK's internal regex implementation, then the regex approach would be O(MN) as well.

Comment: @sln I mean to say that user can call this function with different punctuation array everytime. Like detectAnypunctuation(input, '!#') or detectAnypunctuation(input, '!#$')

Comment: Also, if you're going to make heavy constant calls to this function, when you create a new regex each time, there is that overhead. There is also the general overhead to init the the regex (albeit small). You could make a hash of each passed in punct string where it's value is a compiled regex object. Set a limit, 10 or so. Build it up, even rotate it off. Then if the passed in string matches the hash key, use the regex object assigned to it. For this to work, the punct string must be kept alphabetized in advanced.

Comment: @sln This is what I've implemented. Any scope of improvement ? public static 
    boolean detectPunctuations(String in, String pu){
                    String puQ = “[” + pu + “]”;
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(puQ);
                    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(in);
                    return m.find();        
     }

Answer (score 1):

This is O(n + k):

```
public boolean detectAnyPunctuation(String input, String punctuationArray) {
    Set<Integer> set = punctuationArray
      .chars().boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return input.chars().boxed()
      .filter(set::contains)
      .distinct().count() == set.size();
}
```

All operations are constant time. Total operations is the sum of the lengths of `punctuations` and `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
boolean hit = str.matches(".*[" + punctuation + "].*");
```

There are no punctuation characters that need escaping when used in a character class.

I think you would find the performance to be pretty good. If the punctuation string is a constant, then build the regex pattern once and reuse it.